# Can't click on element by text, if elements have the same text inside

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click on element by text from list of elements, but sometimes elements could have the same text and if statement not executed.

```
public void clickByText() {
        String myText = "Text1";
        List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(myElements);
        for (WebElement e : elements) {
            if (e.getText().equals(myText)) {
                e.click();
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("not exists");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Print this list `elements ` and let us know what is the output

Comment: @cruisepandey elements are span classes with text for example: "Text1", "Text2", "Text1". I nee to click on span class with "Text1" but I have two elements with the same text inside.

Comment: Do you want duplicates, if not try to use set instead of list

Answer (score 0):

1. Maybe don't look for the text by equals, use contains.
2. Remove the break from your code, this makes only the else or only the if block to run only once.

code example:

```
public void clickByText() {
String myText = "Text1";
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(myElements);
for (WebElement e : elements) {
if (e.getText().contains(myText)) {
    e.click();                
} else {
    System.out.println("not exists: " + e.getText());               
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't help to me

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an issue with duplicates. since list in Java can contains duplicates, whereas set do not. try the below code :

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(""));
Set<WebElement> setElements = new HashSet<WebElement>(elements);
    for (WebElement e : elements) {
    // rest of your code
    
    }
```

Comment: I have and error: "incompatible types required list string but collect was inferred to R"

Comment: @Old_the_jackal : Can you try now ? I have updated the code above.

Comment: it doesn't help to me , set elements not executed in this part

Comment: Well it ensure you that you don't have a duplicate data