# Check that two span classes are equal to text and click on the correct span element after

Tags: java, selenium

I have two span elements and I need to check that my text: Frat Brothers (2013) is equal to text inside this span clases and that click on this element.

```xml
<a href="/frat-brothers" class="">
    <span class="name-content-row__row__title">Frat Brothers</span>
    <span class="name-content-row__row--year">(2013)</span>
</a>
```

My code:

```java
String title = "Frat Brothers (2013)";
       List<WebElement> content = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span[class*='name-content-row__'"));
  for (WebElement e : content) {
                System.out.println("elememts is : " + e.getText());
                if (e.getText().equals(title)) {
                    click(e);
}
```

output:

```
elememts is : Frat Brothers
elememts is : (2013)
```

if statment isn't executed.

Comment: Can you add some more context? Do you have other Frat Brothers on the page? Or there is one place where such two spans might appear and your issue is only in that you cannot concatenate texts from those two spans?

Comment: Exactly! I have "Frat Brothers (2014)",  so I can't check only with title. Maybe mapping <List<WebElement>> on my  ArrayList<String>> with titles and getting correct element would resolve problem?

Answer (score 0):

if statment did not execute, cause you have

```
String title = "Frat Brothers (2013)";
```

change that to

```
String title = "Frat Brothers";
```

and you should be good to go.

also do not use  `click(e);` instead it should be `e.click();`

Comment: I need to make certain click on title with year to avoid a bad data, in case i will find two the same items

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68849500/cant-click-on-element-by-text-if-elements-have-the-same-text-inside also I see there isn't any response from your side on this ticket

Comment: also did you make changes as I have suggested, I guess it should work

Comment: `//span[contains(@class, 'name-content-row')]/..` also try this xpath.

Comment: bro, can you give me the page URL ? and what is exactly you wanna perform ?

Comment: it's on local I can't. I want to check if my title is equal to span elements which are containing text, then click on it. The problem is that on the page title consists with two spans, title + year. My string have contains full title with year

Answer (score 0):

`driver.findElements` method accepts `By` parameter while you passing it a String.
In case you want to select elements according to this CSS Selector you can do this:

```
List<WebElement> content = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span[class*='name-content-row__'"));
```

Also, you will get 2 `span` elements, first with text `Frat Brothers` and second with text `(2013)`.
No one of these elements text will NOT be equal to `Frat Brothers (2013)`.
You can check if `title` contains these texts

Comment: yes, you can see,
elememts is : Frat Brothers
elememts is : (2013)
but I need to click on span which contains and title Frat Brothers and year (2013), when I'm checking only if title contains "Frat Brothers" I can click on bad title for example: Frat Brothers (2014)

Comment: OK, if so I think you should adjust your logic here. Why not to click the parent `a` element containing both these `span`s with both their texts?

Comment: I'm trying to check if element exists with list of titles.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following xPath: `//a[normalize-space()='Frat Brothers (2013)']`

So that there would be no need for extra code. Like:

```java
String title = "Frat Brothers (2013)";
WebElement content = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[normalize-space()='" + title + "']"));
content.click();
```

**P.S.** - Here is the xPath test: http://xpather.com/V9cjThsr

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[normalize-space()='Frat Brothers (2013)'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//a[normalize-space()='Frat Brothers (2013)']' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: That is strange.. can you test this expression in browser dev tools?

Answer (score 0):

Text verification, add testng dependency in your pom.xml

```
String title = "Frat Brothers (2013)";
            
// storing text from the element
String first = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span[class*='name-content-row__'")).get(0).getText();
String second = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span[class*='name-content-row__'")).get(1).getText();

// validating the text
  Assert.assertTrue(title.contains(first), "checking name is available in the element");
  Assert.assertTrue(title.contains(second), "checking year is available in the element");
```